# Textbox Form Field Required

Tags: ms-access

I inserted the following VBA code to my textbox in a form. It only works if i type something then delete what i typed. If i go to the next box, then the error message comes out. Is there any way to require the textbox is filled out?

```
Private Sub master_bill_a_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If IsNull(Me.master_bill_a) Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "You must enter a value for 'YourControlNameOrYourDescription'. 
Please make a valid entry or press ESC to Cancel"
    'You could set the focus on the specific control if your wish, change 
the background color, ...
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this form tied to a record source? If so, why don't you just make the back-end field required? If not, it might be better to run the validation when you actually need it. For example, it you have a "Generate Report" button that uses whatever value's in `master_bill_a`, you can have that button's code check the value.

Comment: As @Zack suggested, set field as required and let Access nag users. They will eventually learn. Otherwise, if field must be filled in before record committed, use FORM BeforeUpdate to validate record data. Use textbox ValidationRule and ValidationText properties to validate user input.